# How does dvaita philosophy explain aham brahmaasmi?

Tags: upanishads, dvaita

aham brahmaasmi (I am Brahman) is a famous upanishad sentence. Prima facie, this statement is advaita-friendly because it is saying that jeeva is same as Brahman. But the dvaita philosophy of Madhvacharya says that jeeva is eternally different from Brahman. How dvaita philosophy interpret the aham brahmaasmi saying? Please answer using references.